# Values of multiple keys are getting updated with one update in a hashmap<string,hashmap>

Tags: java, hashmap

the following code is a representation of a hashmap.

I am trying to update the values of 2 keys in this has map one by one, but on the second update both the keys are getting updated (please see the code comments to understand). I am not understanding what am i doing wrong here.

```
 public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> MainHashMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> hmc1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, String> hmc2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, String> hmc3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, String> updateHM = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        hmc1.put("1", "AC");
        hmc1.put("2", "TV");
        hmc2.put("1", "Fan");
        hmc2.put("2", "Light");
        hmc3.put("1", "Iron");
        hmc3.put("2", "Geyser");
        MainHashMap.put("1", hmc1);
        MainHashMap.put("2", hmc2);
        MainHashMap.put("3", hmc3);
        System.out.println(MainHashMap); // printing the mian hasp map with three hash maps
        updateHM.put("1", "Bag");// creating a temp hash map
        updateHM.put("2", "pen");
        MainHashMap.put("1", updateHM); // updating the key 1 of the main hash map
        updateHM.put("1", "jeet");// changing the temp hash map
        updateHM.put("2", "vishu");
        MainHashMap.put("2", updateHM);// updating the key 2 of the main hash map
        System.out.println(MainHashMap);// we see that both the keys are updated
    }

}
```

output:

```
{1={1=AC, 2=TV}, 2={1=Fan, 2=Light}, 3={1=Iron, 2=Geyser}}
{1={1=jeet, 2=vishu}, 2={1=jeet, 2=vishu}, 3={1=Iron, 2=Geyser}}
```

Pleas help.

Thanks

Comment: The underlying bug is called *aliasing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the `updateHM` Map object which is already stored in your `mainMap` against key `1` with value `{1=Bag, 2=pen}`. NOw the following line of code updates the `updateHM`.

```
        updateHM.put("1", "jeet");// changing the temp hashmap
        updateHM.put("2", "vishu");
```

HashMap objects are mutable. So any operation on the HashMap object may affect where it has used. So, if you want to solve your problem then create a new object of HashMap every time you want to update.Use the below code before updating the key `2` in mainMap

```
updateHM = new HashMap<>();
updateHM.put("1", "jeet");// changing the temp hash map
updateHM.put("2", "vishu");
MainHashMap.put("2", updateHM);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) problem resolved. I was under the assumption that MainHashMap.put("1", updateHM); would put the value of the updateHM to 1, but it seems this would make the key 1 to point to this new hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

A new `HashMap` instance is needed here before the update:

```
updateHM = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
updateHM.put("1", "jeet");
updateHM.put("2", "vishu");
MainHashMap.put("2", updateHM);
```